# In uv editing it won't put image on cube

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: as you see, I have an image up but it will not go on the cube. sorry if the question is vague.]
I tried putting blender in render mode, quitting and restarting, going into shading tab (but for me the shading tab is broken) and it still won't work

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped the object?  Have you applied a material to the object with that texture?

Comment: Yes I did unwrap it and did all these little trials, (putting blender in render mode, quitting and restarting, going into shading tab) but still no texture.